# Gradle DSL method not found:'android()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android studio shows possible causes:

The project may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.android.application"
            manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${com.android.application}",
                                    onesignal_app_id:"3z281386-18df-4ae8-95fb-da47db595f27",
                                    onesignal_google_project_number:"570040958475"]
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        } }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0' }
```

Comment: classpath has been changed according to given instruction by firebase

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

As the first line of the build.gradle

Comment: I made some changes instructed by firebase https://ibb.co/bLw2AF and applying your instruction still getting error but this time new error has been found error(1,0) plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Comment: This means you are missing the classpath for the gradle android plugin, like this build.gradle. you need this line https://github.com/matpag/ClickDrawableTextView/blob/master/build.gradle#L8 and your project build.gradle should be pretty similary